# Netbeans TextFlow

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Netbeans keeps telling me that it can't find the textflow class. I am running scene builder 2.0 in conjunction with Netbeans 8.0.1, and for some reason, netbeans is not recognizing the javafx container "TextFlow". What is strange about this is the fact that it recognizes all OTHER fx components that I have used so far, such as textarea, label, etc...

Here is my code:

```
package line.breaks;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Quiggy
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public Label label;
    public TextArea textArea;
    public StackPane stackpane;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        TextFlow textF = new TextFlow();

    }

}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks:)

Comment: Which JavaFX version are you using? `TextFlow` was introduced in JavaFX 8.0. Also note you haven't imported it: does it give an error if you manually add the import?

Comment: I believe that Netbeans 8.0.1 (which I am using) is bundled with JavaFX 8.0. Also, TextFlow shows up in scene builder. I already tried importing it both manually and automatically.

Comment: Just because NetBeans came bundled with Java 8 doesn't mean you are using that version in any given project. Can you [edit] your question to show the version of the code that includes the import? What does the compile error actually say?

Comment: I installed a newer version of Netbeans, and the problem seems to be fixed (I guess it's running the latest version of java and javafx).:) How do I close this question? Sorry, I just joined stack exchange about an hour ago...